# Is it possible to send the results of server actions to a client component in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, server-action

In Next.js 13, I have an API where I post form data, and I want to display errors sent from the backend in a toast on the screen. How can I achieve this with my code?

```
const handleSubmit = async (FormData) => {
"use server";
try {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  const response = await fetch(
    `${Backend_URL}Products/CreateOneProductWithImage`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`,
      },
      body: FormData,
    }
  );
  //Backend'den gelen erorların listesi.
  let BackEndErros = await response.json();
  console.log(BackEndErros);
  error = BackEndErros;

  if (
    response.status === 201 ||
    response.status === 200 ||
    response.status.ok
  ) {
    SuccesToast("Başarılı");
    return { message: "Success!" };
  } else {
    BackEndErros &&
      BackEndErros.map((item, key) => {
        return ErrorToast(
          item.value.length > 2 ? item.value[1] : item.value[0],
          key
        );
      });
    return { message: "There was an error." };
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("An error occurred:", error);
}
revalidateTag("Products")};
```